# How to add name to fabricjs object?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In order to get fabricjs canvas image by name, I need to set unique id or name to this iamge. I've created a new class `fabric.NamedImage` 
That's how I did it.

```
  fabric.NamedImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {

  type: 'nameimage',

  initialize: function (element, options) {
      this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
      options && this.set('name', options.name);
  },

  toObject: function () {
      return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), { name: this.name });
  },

  _render: function (ctx) {
      this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
  }});
```

And fromObject

```
 fabric.NamedImage.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
      fabric.util.loadImage(object.src, function (img) {
          var instance = new fabric.NamedImage(img, object);
          callback && callback(instance);
      });
  };
  fabric.NamedImage.async = true;
```

But when I'm trying to load canvas `loadFromJSON` for some reasons I keep getting error

```
cannot read property 'async' of undefined
```

Here is code where I'm trying to load JSON

```
for (i = 0; i <= canvas.length; i++) {
                    JSON.parse(imageQuery[i]);
                canvas[i].loadFromJSON(imageQuery[i]);
                        canvas[i].renderAll();
                        console.log(' this is a callback. invoked when canvas is loaded!xxx ');              
            }
```

I've already read 
[cannot read property 'async' of undifined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384804/fabric-js-subclassing-fabric-group-error-cannot-read-property-async-of-und)
and
[save canvas to server with custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272772/fabric-js-how-to-save-canvas-on-server-with-custom-attributes)

Is there some way to get object by name?

Answer (score 2):

From the official docs,

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect();

rect.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      name: this.name
    });
  };
})(rect.toObject);

canvas.add(rect);

rect.name = 'trololo';

console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));
```

and the logged output will be

```
'{"objects":[{"type":"rect","left":0,"top":0,"width":0,"height":0,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":false,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"rx":0,"ry":0,"name":"trololo"}],"background":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"}'
```

Please refer this http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Plesae change the type property of your class to 'namedImage' and it should go.

Comment: Still doesn't work with the same error. I've changed 'nameimage' to 'namedImage"

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom properties to different objects in fabric js using the code given below:

```
obj.toObject = (function (toObject) {
    return function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this),{
            id : value
        });
    };
})(obj.toObject);
```

Here obj is the canvas object that you have created and `id` is the custom attribute we are adding to this object. 
Suppose you have saved canvas in the form of a json file. So while using json.stringify consider the code below:

```
json_data = JSON.stringify(self.canvas.toJSON(['attribute1', 
'attrubute2']));
```

Here in square brackets include all the custom attributes. Later on when you will use loadfromjson all the custom properties will automatically be included. Hope it will work. Have a nice day!!