# Fabrics.js - loadFromJSON() fails when JSON includes item of type 'shape'

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm currently working on business card designing platform using `fabrics.js`.

I'm trying to implement auto-save feature which protects users from losing work by saving and restoring the designing data in browser cache.

So I used `loadFromJSON()` of `Fabrics.js` Canvas object to restore the designing data.

But I'm getting following error when I try to restore `shape` item from the JSON.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'async' of undefined`

Following is the my fiddle to test this. I have embedded raw JSON in the javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/asgriksen/mhf2kqzo/14/

Thanks.

Comment: The link is missing. Can you edit your post and add it?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the fiddle link.

Comment: I tried toDatalessJSON() and loadFromDatalessJSON() instead of toJSON() and loadFromJSON(), but I got the same error.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384804/fabric-js-subclassing-fabric-group-error-cannot-read-property-async-of-und.  If you are using a custom class (which it sounds like 'shape' is), there's a couple of gotchas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object at index 4 is a object of type `shape`. There is no fabric object of that type. I will assume you created a custom class for that object?

If so you need to add it to fabric so it can find it when trying to rebuild that object from the json. Assuming you have a new fabric shape class in a variable called `Shape` of which the data you link to is already set to type of `shape` you just need to add it to fabric like this

```
fabric.Shape= Shape;
fabric.Shape.async = false;
```

now fabric should be able to find the class when you load in the data.

if you still have issues with this I recommend including more of the code in the jsfiddle.